# how do you get a specific value searched by a value in dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get a specific value from the DataFrame. But I want to get this value searched by a value.

I've been trying the df.loc[df['word']=='apple','count'] .

This gives me the index and the count. What I want is only the count so that I can use this as a number to calculate things around.

```
d = {'word' : ['apple', 'banana'], 'count' : [1,2] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.loc[df['word']=='apple','count']
```

I expected or wanted the output to be 1

and the type to be an integer or float,
but the output is:

0     1

Name: count, dtype: int64

Comment: I get 1 as the output (0 as the index and 1 as the value of the count Series). Are you sure you're running exactly this code? Because there's a missing `}` in it, so I assume you didn't just copy-paste exactly what you ran. Were you expecting to get the integer 1 instead of a `pandas.Series` where the only value is 1?

Comment: oops sorry I made some mistakes in my question 'cause I was making a short dataframe to show as a demo. But is there a way to get just  1.  and 1 as an integer type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.loc` returns a `pandas.Series`, even if there is only one element in that series. One way to get a raw value from a series is to index it at a single location. Adding `.iloc[0]` to your code produces the desired result:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'word': ['apple', 'banana'], 'count': [1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.loc[df['word'] == 'apple', 'count'].iloc[0]
```

Comment: Yeah!! It's working. I kept trying df.loc[df['word']=='apple','count'][0]  dumb me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hm, what you were trying should have worked as well. For a dataframe, doing `df[0]` would try to access a *column* named 0, but for a series that should work. I used `.iloc` because I'm more used to accessing the first element (row) in a dataframe. Note that the type of the number will be `numpy.int64` not `int`, but this probably doesn't matter.